# How hard is to find programming job in France when I speak only english

Tags: job-search, france

I am java developer with three years of experience and I would like to move to France for at least a year. I use english everyday and I want to learn French on basic level before moving. I want to continue learning French when I will be there. How hard is to find a job in software industry in France without good French?

Comment: As a plain Java developer with just 3 years experience, you are "one in a zillion", relatively far down the food chain. A French employer will then strongly prefer a french citizen, not only because of French employment laws, but also because of the language. If you have special skills (special frameworks or techs), however, you should establish contact to a French hiring agent (e.g. via LinkedIn/XING) specialized in technology jobs. If searching for yourself, you would have to be really lucky to find a good job that only requires basic language skills.

Comment: Having worked in the French speaking part of Switzerland, I'd say it's not really a good way to learn spoken French, because as soon as people realize you're a native English speaker but not fluent in French, they switch to English to practice.  (Good for reading, though.)  Also, as Alexander says, it's not easy to get a job unless you have rare skill sets that the employer can't fill locally.

Comment: I can't imagine you getting a job in France with your qualifications and experience if you don't even speak the language. If you just want to go for the 'French experience' then you're probably more likely to get a remote job in your own country and make the move. I actually live in a different country from my main income stream.

Comment: Frenh market is different than others in that it really focuses on young people with shiny diplomas. Beyond the age 35/40, it's tough to stay developper there. I'd say, it really depends on your age. If you are far below 30 and have a shiny diploma, you can try your luck with "SSII", the powerful local consulting firms, like Cap Gemini, Sopra, or GFI(for example). There's not much places at all outside those firms, anyways.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting a job with an multinational company that has an office in France, and prove to them you can do good work, before requesting a transfer to the office there.  Then you'll be seen as much less of a risk because the company already knows how you do working for them, AND you may have teams/projects in other offices you continue collaborating with remotely, still adding value to the company there.